# MySQL nested And/Or condition index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM my_table WHERE column_A = x AND (column_B = y OR column_C = z)
```

Question:

Is it possible to index column A,B,C in such a way that this query only uses index to finish. If not, what is the best way to index these 3 columns?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If column_A is a primary index axis (ie. first column in the index), that will cover the “AND” very well. Then ensure B and C are either part of the index key (it probably doesn’t matter which is first) or are columns included in the index. In that case the [single] index will (more than likely) be used for the query.

Comment: ..and then as always check the QP for estimates and actual execution related to data. If it’s possible that B “OR” C somehow changes the selectivity (ie. results in a very small number of rows compared to A), such can be explored.. otherwise probably not an issue.

Comment: While selecting between `(a,b,c)` and `(a,c,b)` you'd compare the selectivity by `b` and `c` for the rows set which matches the condition by `a`. The column which' condition is less selective (shows more matches) should be placed second, and the rest column should be last. Anycase you'll see 'using index, using where' in the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(A,B,C)
```

but do *not* also have `INDEX(A)`; the Optimizer may pick the "shorter" index instead of the "covering" index.

Selectivity does not play any role.  So `INDEX(A,C,B)` is just as good.  And the only indexes that will be considered are those *starting with* `A`.

**Elaboration**

`OR` cannot use an index, however a "covering index" can help.  Let me explain.  A "covering index" is one that has all the columns needed in the query.  But why does that matter?  Well, if you have, say, just `INDEX(A)`, the Index is used to find the rows in the Index's BTree that have the appropriate value(s) for A, then, for each such row, it reaches over into the data's BTree to find the entire row.  At that point, it can check `B=y OR C=z` by brute force.

If, instead, you have `INDEX(A,B,C)`, then all 3 of those columns are in the Index BTree and the full check can be performed without reaching into the data's Btree.  (It is still brute force when it comes to the `OR`, but the secondary lookup is avoided.)

Comment: Just wondering how can the OR condition part utilize this index (A, B, C)? Won't this query only use the A part of this composite index? Thanks

Comment: @yoyo - I elaborated.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rick James. Just a minor question, when you say "data's B-Tree", I think maybe you mean going back to table to fetch rows? Only index is using the B-Tree right? Thanks

Comment: There are two separate BTrees.  When the query can be performed in the index's BTree, the index is called "covering" because it won't have to touch the other BTree.  So, it is not really using the index do do "OR", but instead to avoid the extra effort of repeatedly reaching into the other BTree (via the PK).